# AttributeRouting: Multiple routes based on user roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

thank you for your reply,
i added BeginExecuteCore in base controller like this
 `public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            //string email = string.Empty;
            dbEntities dbcontext = new dbEntities();

```
        var userRoleName = (from n in dbcontext.VAgentClientEmails where n.Email == User.Identity.Name select n.Role).FirstOrDefault();

        if (userRoleName == "SuperAdmin")
            RouteData.Values["role"] = userRoleName;

        else 
            RouteData.Values["role"] = "";

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }`
```

and i have given in home controller like this

`[Route("~/{role}/SavedSearch/Index")]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
  ...
  }`

its working for admin/savedsearch/index
and also if i give fjsdfk/savedsearch/index its working
in the above case it should not work..

and in else case i dont want role

do i need to do any changes?

Comment: dont want to show controller name?